# Failure to import sknn.mlp / Theano

Tags: python, installation, attributes, scikit-learn, theano

I'm trying to use scikit-learn's neural network module in iPython... running Python 3.5 on a Win10, 64-bit machine.

When I try to import `from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer` , I get back the following `AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'gof'` ...

The command line highlighted for the error is `class DisconnectedType(theano.gof.type.Type)`, within **theano\gradient.py**

Theano version is 0.8.2, everything installed via pip.

Any lights on what may be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Try installing the bleeding edge version of Theano from here: [link](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was caused by some issue with Visual Studio. The import worked when I reinstalled VS and restarted the computer.

Thanks @super_cr7 for the prompt reply!